# Does a group morphism factor through a quotient group?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

I'm about to solve 3 exercice sierge lang algebra third edition:

> Let $G^c$ be the sub-group generated by commutator. Question: Show that $G^c$ is normal sub-group of $G$ and show that every homomorphism of $G $ onto an abelian group $G^\prime $ factor through $G / G^c  $.

For the first one it is easy, but for the second this is my attempt:

Let $f:G \rightarrow G $ a group homomorphism and consider the canonical projection $\pi : G \rightarrow G^c $ by the first iso theorem there is a unique $\alpha$ s.t for all $g \in G$, $ \alpha (\pi (g))=f(g)$.

Comment: The exercise wants the following. Given $f:G\to G'$ with $G'$ abelian there exists a homomorphism $\alpha: G/G^c \to G'$ such that $f=\alpha\circ\pi$.

Comment: but f is not surjective

Comment: It sure looks like you cannot assume $f$ to be surjective. You need to use something else.

Comment: **Hint:** If $f:G\to G'$ is a homomorphism where $G'$ is Abelian, then all commutator elements $[x,y]\in G^c$ are in $\ker(f)$.

Comment: Berci .awsome thanks for your help

Comment: so can say that $   G/ G^c  $ is an abelian group?

Comment: You cannot assert that from *this* theorem (the result also applies to other subgroups where the quotient is *not* necessarily abelian, for example, $(G^c)^c$). You have to *prove* that $G/G^c$ is abelian directly.

Comment: Arturo Magidin $(G^c)^c $  subgroup of the commutator group ?

Comment: Of course: it's the commutator subgroup of $G^c$, hence a (normal) subgroup of $G^c$. But in fact, it is also a normal subgroup of $G$ itself.